# C++ linux argv dash parameters

Tags: c++, linux, string

I have been trying to work with C++ console app on linux.

I want to change the options of the user depending on what parameter he used.

Like: `./my -n 1234` or `./my -f file.txt`

-n or -f is always argv[1]
1234 or file.txt is always argv[2]

my main()

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Here is my code so far:

```
string numlist, num;


if (argc < 3) {
   fprintf(stderr,"usage stuff...%s %s", argv[0], argv[0]);
   exit(0);
}

char *f = "-f";
char *n = "-n";
char *argv0 = argv[0];
char *argv1 = argv[1];
char *argv2 = argv[2];

if (strcmp(argv1, f) == 0){
    numlist = argv[2];
    //more data for this parameter
}

if (strcmp(argv1, n) == 0){
    num = argv[2];
    //more data for this parameter
}
```

Problem:

when i try `./my -n 1234`
This should skip 1st if block, then execute 2nd if block.
or `./my -f file.txt`
Should execute the 1st if block, and skip the 2nd if block.

Now with my current code if i enter either -n or -f it skips all if blocks.

-- edit --
I guess I fixed it the problem was actually not on the argv but on my if blocks.

Thanks everyone I'll check all your suggestions.

Comment: No idea what you are asking

Comment: what do you mean with "typed in the parameter". I suppose your code is in `int main(int argc, char**argv)` and you've called your code with, say, `./my -f` is this so?

Comment: What exactly does it skip? You're saying that neither of the last two if blocks are entered?

Comment: The code is accessing `argv` elements _before_ it has confirmed the number of elements in `argv`. (It did, until you edited the question which suggests this is not the exact code).

Comment: btw, why not using `boost::program_options`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what's your complete source code but here is what it worked for me:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    if (argc < 3) {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage stuff...%s %s", argv[0], argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }

    string numlist;
    string num;

    char *f = "-f";
    char *n = "-n";
    char *argv0 = argv[0];
    char *argv1 = argv[1];
    char *argv2 = argv[2];


    if (strcmp(argv1, f) == 0){
        numlist = argv[2];
       //more data for this parameter
    }

    if (strcmp(argv1, n) == 0){
        num = argv[2];
    //more data for this parameter
    }
}
```

I've added the `using namespace std` to make the writing of the code easier, also i've moved the validation to the top, because if argv[2] doesn't exists, it will throw an error.

Comment: i tried moving it to the top too. and still the same thing. it still skips both the if blocks.

Comment: It's the same as char argv[][], it's an array of made of words.

Comment: i choose this answer because it gave me the idea of moving the argc check to the top.

Answer (score 1):

Does [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/13355/) help? It looks like a neat way to parse command arguments.

(And a more complicated [one](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DEN36Up4/), although I think the first is good enough)

Comment: Very useful links. I think a for loop using argc and a check using argv are enough to work with these parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to do this as an exercise for yourself, you should probably use a library function for this.

Walter has already mentioned [boost::program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/program_options.html). If you do not want to work with Boost, you can also have a look at [getopt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt), which is a tried and true C library function.

Comment: I second boost program_options. If you use C++ and boost, you should use program_options.

Answer (score 0):

Add some output statement to your if-clauses, like `printf("this is option -f\n")`, I'd bet you will see that it does not skip both if-bodies, only one.

Looks like you are not very familiar with string handling in C++. Look for `std::string` and see how you can do things easier using strings than using `char*`. I would assume that using  boost is better left to more experienced programmers, but you can give it a try,

Comment: yes both have different prints. none of them are getting displayed. and yes, im really new.

Comment: I copied your code, inserted the print-outs, and it works for me. Are you calling it with two arguments, like `./my -n 1234`? Calling it with just two arguments will skip both if-bodies (but should give the usage statement)